# How to extract trace stack where function directly raises an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

For some reason there is no such frame in the stack.

For example, if I have a simple function in foo.py:

```
def foo(a):
    if a < 0:
        raise Exception('a must be > 0.')
```

and do (from another file detect.py):

```
try:
    foo(-1)
except Exception as e:
    error = traceback.extract_stack()
    print(error)
```

The result: `[<FrameSummary file detect.py, line 16 in <module>>]`

Then we see the only FrameSummary from current file where exception occurs, there are no FrameSummary about direct place (line content and line_no) where exception raised (in foo.py).

Are there method to extract the information?

Answer (score 0):

How to do it. I found a solution (thanks to inspect module and guys which worked on it):

```
import sys
import traceback
import inspect
from foo import foo

try:
    foo(-1)
except Exception as e:
    inner_frames = inspect.getinnerframes(e.__traceback__)
    print('File names: {}.'.format([x.filename for x in inner_frames]))
    print('Called in functions: {}.'.format([x.function for x in inner_frames]))
    print('Line numbers: {}.'.format([x.lineno for x in inner_frames]))

...

File names: ['detect.py', '/home/sergzach/Dropbox/tests/exception_detect_module/foo.py'].
Called in functions: ['<module>', 'foo'].
Line numbers: [12, 4].
```